# My bootstrap 3 responsive navbar doesn't collapse.

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

I just started this project but I just can't get the navbar right. Read every same question on stack but I can't figure it out. Tried the jquery everywhere and screened my code now about a 100 times.

```
<title>Dit is Bas</title>

<meta name "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<link type="css/bootstrap.min" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Bas</a>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Photo's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Bas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Hopefully somebody will see the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in `data-target="collapse navbar-collapse"` which should be `id` of `div` that has items of menu. For transitions to work in Bootstrap you need jquery.js before bootstrap.js.

You should have something like this to have working navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#important-id-for-collapsing" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="important-id-for-collapsing">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's a link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dejanmarolt/04v7outb/).

Comment: Tried what you said but unfortunately it still doesn't work.. Tried a couple browsers and had no result. Thought I was making a typo so I copied what you said. That doesn't work either.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Code above was working before, but you were probably missing link to jquery.js. You can also check working example on JSFiddle.